# 415 error when sending data to a server

Tags: json, cordova, http

I am building an app using ionic/cordova that will take a scan, store this to the device (this part works), and also upload this data to a server (this part doesn't work).

The server is a RESTful api that expects JSON to be POSTed (I didn't create the server, these are the details I have been given).

When I try to post to the server I am getting the following error -

```
{status: 415, url: "http://jsfitnessservice.azurewebsites.net/api/values123", headers: {…}, error: ""} error:""
headers:
content-length:"0"
date:"Tue, 06 Feb 2018 19:41:36 GMT"
request-context:"appId=cid-v1:bf5436d9-7e1e-491e-b79d-d40d9b401307"
server:"Kestrel"
x-android-received-millis:"1517946100312"
x-android-response-source:"NETWORK 415"
x-android-selected-protocol:"http/1.1"
x-android-sent-millis:"1517946100070"
x-powered-by:"ASP.NET"
```

My code -

```
let httpData = {
      "id": this.device.uuid,
      "scanDateTimes": this.lastScans,
      "appVersion": "Version 1.0"
      }

    let header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    this.http.post('http://jsfitnessservice.azurewebsites.net/api/values 123', httpData, header).then 
    (data =>{
      console.log("Data Status - ", data.status);
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log("Error  - ", error)
    });
```

I have tried a few things that I have seen online, such as adding the header to an object, or using JSON.Stringify() around the data I am sending. But these give errors too.

JSON.stringify around data gives this error  -

```
status: -1, error: "unsupported params type, needs to be a JSON object"
```

Making header an object gives this error -

```
status: 0, error: "advanced-http: header values must be strings",   headers: {…}}
```

Comment: Are you using ionic-native http  or angular http ? from your syntax it looks like it is native angular but from the error message , it appears as if it is  native http ?

Comment: Using ionic-native/http

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
this.http.setDataSerializer(‘json’)
this.http.post('http://jsfitnessservice.azurewebsites.net/api/values 123', httpData, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}).then 
(data =>{
  console.log("Data Status - ", data.status);
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log("Error  - ", error)
});
```

Comment: I added an extra line at the top . Please see if that helps you out

Comment: This seems to have fixed this error. However now I'm getting a mix of a 200 message (successful) and a error message of 502 which says - The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Oh and when I get the 200 message, no data is actually being added to the servers database.

Comment: These are server issues. You should talk to the guys behind the server . They cannot be resolved from client side